# In GnuPG, how do I set an absolute date for expiry on my key?

Tags: gnupg

In GnuPG I can edit the expiry of my key like this:

```
$ gpg --edit-key 01234567
[...]

gpg> expire
Changing expiration time for the primary key.
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
Key is valid for? (0)
```

But what if I want to set the expiry to a specific (absolute) date/time, e.g. 01-01-2015, midnight? Do I really have to calculate the exact time from now, e.g. 9m+15d+...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output of GnuPG on how to specify the expiry is missing the option to just enter an ISO date in the form of YYYY-MM-DD. Unlike the help text suggests it would not be valid, it will just work:

```
Key is valid for? (0) 2015-01-01
Key expires at Thu 01 Jan 2015 00:00:00 CET
```

Comment: It doesn’t accept `2038-01-01T00:00:00Z` but `20380101T000000Z`, for what it’s worth.

Comment: ...And this way it won’t set the `Key Expiration Time (0x9)` subpacket value minute-level-accurately. Mine have differences of a few minutes.

Comment: @КонстантинВан, this seems to be resolved at least as of `gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.24`.